# Wordpress error when updating PHP to version 8.0

Tags: php, wordpress, php-8

I am trying to update the PHP version to 8.0 on an old WordPress site. It works fine on PHP 7.4 but when I switch to PHP 8.0 I get the following error:

`There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.`
This is for anything in the admin.

The error log shows:
`Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ini_set() /public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:7527`

This is line 7527 in `functions.php`

```
if ( false !== ini_set( 'memory_limit', $wp_max_limit ) ) {
```

Stack trace:

```
Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(162): wp_raise_memory_limit('admin')
#1 /public_html/wp-admin/post.php(12): require_once('/home/MYAPPNAME/...')
#2 {main}
```

Comment: `ini_set` is a core function, and should always be defined. Either something is wrong with your PHP installation, or the function has been disabled. Check your php.ini for `disable_functions`

Comment: The function was disabled by my hosting provider. I added an `ini_set` function in my wp-config.php file and just returned false. That has sorted it.

Comment: How about naming and shaming that hosting provider? Who are they? So we can avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the bottom of your `wp-config.php` file:

```
function ini_set() {
    return;
}
```